# Decipher Python Problem with One Time Pad

Tags: python

I am new to programming and am trying to create a program where I am given a one time pad and want to decipher a  basic message file using my program. I am having trouble matching up the ASCII and pad (I can't figure out a "code" or formula for my shift in characters). Any and all help will be greatly appreciated. I have set pad = 9 because idk what or how to shift the letters. Here is the pad I was given:

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

Which I saved as a text file and then read in.

```
msg = "This is an amazing secret message!"

pad = open("pad.txt", "r")

shift = 9

def shift_letter(c,shift):
    pad_count = 0
    code = ord(c)
    if (code>=65) and (code<=90):
        code = ((code-shift-39)%26)+65
        pad_count = pad_count + 1
    elif (code>=97) and (code<=122):
        code = (code-shift-71)%26+97
    return chr(code)

def shift_message(msg, shift):
    seq = list(msg)
    for i in range(0,len(msg)):
        seq[i] = shift_letter(seq[i],shift)
    return "".join(seq)

def encrypt(msg):
    return shift_message(msg,shift)

def decrypt(msg):
    return shift_message(msg,shift)

def main ():
    encrypted_message = encrypt(msg)
    print(encrypted_message)

    final_message = decrypt(encrypted_message)
    print(final_message)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Improved formatting

Comment: "because idk what or how to shift the letters" - what do you mean by this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to read the shift from your pad file:

```
with open("pad.txt") as f:
    pad = f.read()

def letter_ord(letter):
    return ord(letter.upper())-ord("A")

def shift_letter(old, shift):
    old = old.upper()
    new_ord = ord(old)+shift
    if new_ord > ord("Z"):
        new_ord -= 26
    elif new_ord < ord("A"):
        new_ord += 26
    return chr(new_ord)

def crypt(text, mode=1):  # mode is 1 for encrypt and -1 for decrypt
    res = ""
    for t_text, t_pad in zip(text, pad):
        res += shift_letter(t_text, letter_ord(t_pad)*mode)
    return res

def encrypt(text):
    return crypt(text, 1)

def decrypt(text):
    return crypt(text, -1)
```

Comment: They want one time pad, not Caesar.

Comment: @bereal I changed it to one time pad now.